# Google analytics to track page hit source

Tags: google-analytics

How can i track the origin of the pages with google analytics. ie from which source its navigated to the current page, whether the page is browsed by clicking on a link in the mail etc.

​Thanks

Comment: This is provided by default when you install the main snippet, so if you have session in you report you might have this information: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/?hl=es-419  . You can find this information under the Acquisition Report. Remember that Stackoverflow is related to programming issues: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Thank you got it